# React Native app, does not show in iPhone setting app

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode11.6

I am new to react native, When I run the `iOS` project from Xcode, it is installed successfully.
However, I am not able to see my app in the setting app of the iPhone.

Xcode Version - 11.6
iphone version - 13.7

Although I am getting following error when checked the devices in organizer.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried unpairing and repairing your iOS device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an issue for that but a workaround is to just add a settings bundle to your iOS project.

Adding the Settings Bundle:

1. Open your workspace's Xcode project file in the ios folder.
2. Select File > New > New File.
3. Under iOS, choose "Resource", and then select the "Settings Bundle" template.
4. Name the file `Settings.bundle`.