# React Native application doesn't show up on settings in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

My config:

```
react-native: 0.66.3
xcode: 13.2.1
```

When deploying an application to the simulator, or to real device, I cannot access the settings page of the app in iOS.

I have a button that asks for user location, and I should at least see it on the settings page.

I tried to deploy the application on release variant, but same thing.
I checked some solution on the web, [and I found a solution with many upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63779093/1056254) but it still did not do the trick.

Maybe there is a way to generate a Settings.bundle with cocoa based to the permission that we have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I came across this and I followed these instructions :

> Adding the Settings Bundle Open your workspace inner ios folder with
> xcode To add a Settings bundle to your Xcode project: Choose File >
> New > New File. Under iOS, choose Resource, and then select the
> Settings Bundle template. Name the file Settings.bundle.

My application was available on the Settings application on iOS, and I just updated the file with my permissions.

From now, the purpose of this file is to manually add some permission, or information (like the version code).

But the automatic permissions like geolocation will be added automatically.

Comment: I've already tested this case, and as you said, you should create manually all the settings, which I don't think it's normal. Because this is not the way before.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. The automatic ones will be added directly.

Comment: You're right it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on github and worked for me

`I solved it by adding a new Settings bundle to my project using Xcode and it then appeared.

File > New > File..
Choose "Settings Bundle" from the list.

It all works fine now. You'll need to remove the placeholder Preference Items from the Root.plist in the Settings Bundle you have added to clean up.`